# H2o.explain confusion matrix

Tags: r, h2o, confusion-matrix, automl

I am trying to understand how the confusion matrix in h2o.explain is generated.
If I use the following code:
h2o.explain(model@leader, test_set, include_explanations="confusion_matrix"), is the generated confusion matrix evaluating the model accuracy on the test set?
How would this be different from using h2o.predict on the test set (e.g. h2o.predict(model@leader, test_set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `h2o.explain` uses the provided `test_set`. The confusion matrix itself in your case is generated by `h2o.confusionMatrix(object = model@leader, newdata = test_set)`.

[Confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) aggregates the data from `h2o.predict` thus providing some high level view on how does the model perform. `h2o.predict` gives you individual predictions without any aggregation.